# Mostrar una imagen por un pedido GET Ajax (axios) de vue js 2 y mostrarla por html 5

Tags: javascript, html5, vue.js

Este es mi codigo quiero hacer un llamado `GET` de axios por Vue.JS y que luego de tener la imagen, que la muestre en html

```
        getImage(param) {
            axios.get(param)
            .then((resp) => {
                return this.image  = resp.data;
            }).catch((err)=>{
                console.log(err)
            });
        }
```

html en realidad es el template de vue pero va dentro de un html 5

```
               <picture>
                <img
                    src= getImage(auto.car.images.file) > // suponiendo que file contiene una url que lleva al lugar de la pagina contenedora de la imagen
                </picture>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que estás poniendo en el atributo `src` el estado de una promesa (`[pending]`); recuerda bien, una Promesa es asíncrona y un callback también lo es; no esperes que esté disponible en el llamante lo que devuelve una promesa o un callback porque no obtendrás el valor esperado.

Lo que debes hacer es hacer un bind del `src` a una variable o propiedad de un objeto y luego, ejecutar el método que `getImage` para que actualice dicha variable con la imagen obtenida y que ésta se vea reflejada automáticamente en el HTML.

**Ejemplo**

```js
new Vue({
  data: function() {
    return {
      profilepic: null,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    getImage(url) {
      this.profilepic = 'https://widgetsdataifx.blob.core.windows.net/widgetsdataifx/Content/themes/Davivienda/images/loading_spinner.gif';
      return axios.get(url, { responseType: 'arraybuffer' });
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    this
      .getImage('https://crossorigin.me/https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.109336634.1604/flat,550x550,075,f.u1.jpg')
      .then(({ data }) => {
        // simulamos una carga
        setTimeout(() => {
        // convertimos el buffer en base64
        const image = btoa(
          new Uint8Array(data)
            .reduce((acc, byte) => acc + String.fromCharCode(byte), '')
        );
        this.profilepic = `data:image/png;base64,${image}`;
        }, 1500);
      });
  },
}).$mount('#app');
```

```css
img {
  border: 4px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  display: block;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 25px auto;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.4/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.16.2/axios.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <img :src="profilepic" />
</div>
```